# Layer to use the @Transactional annotation in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Data JPA for my application, which has the following layers:

1. **Service layer** with Interfaces and Implements (annotated @service)
2. **CRUD repository layer** with Spring Data JPA, together with custom repository implementations
3. **Entity layer**

I was wondering where exactly is the correct place to put `@Transactional`. Currently, I have it in the service layer, where the repositories are being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transactions belong to Service layer. For example if you have `HotelService`, then the code would look like this:

```
@Service("hotelService")
@Transactional
public class HotelServiceImpl implements HotelService {
    @Autowired
    HotelDao hotelDao;

    // The rest of code omited ...
}
```

Comment: Also don't you think adding it at function level rather than class level might be better as we have control over readonly transactions etc ?

Comment: @AbhishekRanjan Well, that was just example. I usually define `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` before `class` and then if I need I define `@Transactional(readOnly = false)` before method.

Comment: Ya that sounds right ,what i normally do is define transactional at each function level,but your approach looks cleaner

Answer (score 0):

The correct place to put `@Transactional` annotation is *any* layer if you want to add a transactional behaviour to your code. The code assumed to use a database access. Usually, you can use `@Transactional` on repositories. But if you need,  you can  add it on the service layer as well.

See [Understanding the Spring Framework's declarative transaction implementation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained)

> You can place the `@Transactional` annotation before an interface definition, a method on an interface, a class definition, or a public method on a class. However, the mere presence of the `@Transactional` annotation is not enough to activate the transactional behavior. The `@Transactional` annotation is simply metadata that can be consumed by some runtime infrastructure that is `@Transactional`-aware and that can use the metadata to configure the appropriate beans with transactional behavior.